# Getting data from an object in an ArrayList into GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I have an input file which has several fields separated by whitespace like this:

 
10 416-555-6666 Burgess 15 
15 905-777-8888 Thomas 10 
20 905-111-2222 Morris 5

I have a separate class file 'Record' which is related to the input file that has ID, telephone, Name, Years of Work.

In my main method, I've created an ArrayList of 'Record' objects called employeeList. The ArrayList is filled by a while loop that splits the read input file into their categories, defined by the Record constructor.

My next task is to create a GUI which can display and cycle through the input file, but I'm having trouble designing a way in which the 'Record' objects are being displayed in the Text fields. I've attached an image below to show what I'm trying to get:

[example drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV3py.png)

The next employee button would cycle to the next item on the ArrayList, being the next record object. I've attached my code below and would appreciate any suggestions on what to do next (making a GUI that displays the items ArrayList).

```
package javaapplication4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class App {

private JFrame f;
private JPanel p;
private JButton b1;
private JLabel lab;
private JTextArea empID;
private JTextArea telephone;
private JTextArea name;
private JTextArea yearsWorked;

public App() {

    gui();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {



    File inputFile = new File("Emp.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    ArrayList<Record> employeeList = new ArrayList<Record>();

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {


        String line = in.nextLine();

        String[] peopleInfo = line.split("\\s+");

        int empId = Integer.parseInt(peopleInfo[0]);
        String telephone = peopleInfo[1];
        String name = peopleInfo[2];
        int years_of_Work = Integer.parseInt(peopleInfo[3]);

        employeeList.add(new Record(empId, telephone, name, years_of_Work));

    }

    new App();
}

  public void gui() {

    f = new JFrame("UpdateEmp");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(600,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    p = new JPanel();

    b1 = new JButton("Test");
    lab = new JLabel();

    empID = JTextField();
    telephone = JTextField();
    name = JTextField();
    yearsWorked = new JTextField();


    p.add(b1);
    p.add(lab);

    f.add(p);
}

}
```

Comment: The App needs the employeeList to display. So you should pass it to its constructor, and store it into a field.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this depending on if you want it done quick or well-designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move your list of records to the class that needs access to it (`App`) rather than being a local variable in the `main` method. You will also need an instance variable to record the index of the current record:

```
class App {
    private final List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentRecord = 0;
    ...
}
```

I would suggest moving your logic for reading the records to a method of `App` so that you don't need to pass it around. Your `main` method should be very simple. Something like:

```
App app = new App();
app.readRecords();
app.showGui();
```

To show the records you will need methods to set the fields you've created as well as 'next' and 'previous' methods.

```
private void showRecord() {
    assert currentRecord >= 0 && currentRecord < records.size();
    Record record = records.get(currentRecord);
    telephoneField.setText(record.getTelephone());
    ...
}

private void previous() {
    if (currentRecord > 0) {
        currentRecord--;
        showRecord();
    }
}

private void next() {
    if (currentRecord < records.size() - 1) {
        currentRecord++;
        showRecord();
    }
}
```